# Попытка установить QLayout в QMainWindow

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, qlayout, qmainwindow

Это код выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on Example "", 
> which already has a layout.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.show()
        self.box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.box)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Qt Main Window Framework
>
> Главное окно предоставляет структуру для создания пользовательского интерфейса приложения.
>
> Qt имеет QMainWindow и связанные с ним классы для управления главным окном.
>
> **QMainWindow имеет свой собственный макет**, к которому вы можете добавить QToolBars, QDockWidgets, QMenuBar и QStatusBar.
>
> Макет имеет центральную область, которая может быть занята любым виджетом. Вы можете увидеть изображение макета ниже.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        self.show()
        
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)  
        
        self.box = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
#        self.setLayout(self.box)
        self.box.addWidget(QLabel("Hello World"))
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]